# Merge maps in java

Tags: java, merge, maps

What i'm trying to do is pretty simple.I want to merge two maps.
Say

```
map1={(1,"one"),(2,"two"),(3,"three");
map2={(1,"onetoo"),(4,"four")};
```

if i follow this->

```
map3.putall(map1);
map3.putall(map2);
```

then value of 1 is onetoo but when i follow the reverse it is one.
is there anyway i could change that?what i mean is that java overwrites and puts only the latest value for a key.
i.e if onetoo was added after one (in their respective maps)then no matter what the order of putall calls to map3 the value remains onetoo.

Comment: Can you give an example of the map you want it to create?

Comment: What do you expect after merging?

Comment: You should definitely create an example to show what you mean. But I think if you want to achieve that, you will have to either create your own `TimedMap extends Map` or do it manually by saving the timestamp of every `put` with the according Element and do the merging by iterating over your maps and only add the element, if there is no entry with that key and a lower timestamp on the corresponding element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to do that, unless you store the actual time when the values were added.

Say `map1={(1,("one", 15:15)), (2, ("two", 15:16))}`

Then you can add all of map1 and then iterate over map2 adding only if the key is not already there or if it's there but with a earlier timestamp.

Comment: I'm gonna go try this.Was concerned about iteration overheads but since there is no way out will use this..thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

That's how maps work, they use the hashcode of the object you set as key as a way to identify its self within the map entries, and as you can see it has to be unique.

So you would have to specify another key since an integer value of 1 has a hashcode of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your programe worked as you want, then predict the output of the following

```
 map3.get(1);
```

You could never know whether it is "One" or "Onetoo".

Too prevent any such problem, Maps in Java are designed to contain only unique keys.

So , if you write

```
map3.putall(map1);
```

the value of 1 is "one". but as soon as you write

```
map3.putall(map2);
```

the value of 1 is reset and it becomes "onetoo". reverse happens when you reverse it. Possible solutions could be.

1. Put in your keys in maps in such a way that they (keys) uniquely identifies an object. So that whenever in future you merge maps, no clash happens(in terms of duplicity) in keys.
2. If you can't do it, then a possible solution could be to get all keys of every map and check for duplicity and change the duplicate keys in such a way that you can retrieve your objects without hassle.

Comment: word to the wise: the method is capitalized as putAll, not putall: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll(java.util.Map)